# Loading constants file into application -Golang

Tags: web-applications, go, server, constants

i have a constants file in my main pkg:

```
package main

const (
  FIRST_NAME                    = "FIRST_NAME"
  LAST_NAME                     = "LAST_NAME"
)
```

and i'd like to be able to say something like `first_name := constants.FIRSTNAME`

any idea on how to tell my application "hey, load my constants file and let me access it with constants."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a separate package called "constants" if you really want them to be constants.

Or, since your constants aren't really constants (you're using `var`, not `const`), you could make a `constants` struct with the values you want.

```
type Constants struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
}
```